# How to find some successive letters letters in a string without ovelap in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to see if I can find 2 successive letters in a taken string without overlapping .
for example : if there are "HP" and "PH" in the string answer is "YES" and if not answer is "NO" .

e.g :

```
input -----> PHHP
output ----> YES
```

or :

```
input -----> HPPH
output ----> YES
```

and :

```
input -----> PHP
output ----> NO
```

or :

```
input -----> PHAP
output ----> NO
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work with still scope for optimization.

```
s = 'phhp'

def validate():
  for i in range(len(s)):
    if len(s[i:i+2]) != 2:
      break
    if 'ph' == s[i:i+2]:
      if 'hp' in s[0:i] or 'hp' in s[i+2:i+4]:
        return True
  return False

print ('Found' if validate() else 'Not Found')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if `'hp'` is in `s` and if it is replace it with `' '` now check if `'ph'` is in `s` if it is return `'YES'`:

```
def func(s):
    s = s.lower()
    if 'hp' in s:
        s = s.replace('hp',' ')
        if 'ph' in s:
            return 'YES'
        else:
            return 'NO'
    else:
        return 'NO'
print(func('HPHP'))
```

Output:

```
NO
```

Comment: This prints `YES` for `PHP` and `HPH` as well, which the OP doesn't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`re`**.

**Demo:**

```
import re

def validate(string):
    return 'YES' if re.search(r'(PH.*HP)|(HP.*PH)', string) else 'NO'

inputs = ['PHHP', 'HPPH', 'PHP', 'PHAP']

for inp in inputs:
    print(inp, validate(inp))
```

**Output:**

```
PHHP YES
HPPH YES
PHP NO
PHAP NO
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any pair of char, not just PHHP

```
def validator(mystr):
    for i in range(len(mystr) - 2):
        Yo=''.join(reversed(mystr[i+2:i+4]))
        return mystr[i:i+2] == Yo
validator ('PHHP')
#True
```